# Out of Memory Error when running Drill Down Script

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

The purpose of the macro is to avoid creating a new worksheet each time a user double clicks / drills down on a pivot table value. Instead the script copies the data to a dedicated "DrillDown" sheet.

After several clicks, I get an Excel error stating I am out of memory.

The raw dataset is not very big.
I am wondering if there is an issue with the script, or perhaps I need to add something further?
Maybe there is some temp data I need to clear first?

My code:

Module1

```vb
Public CS$
```

This Workbook

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
If CS <> "" Then
    With Application
        ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim NR&
        With Sheets("DrillDown")

            'Set this to always start at the top of the page
            NR = 1
            '..and to clear the Drilldown tab..
            .Cells.ClearContents

            'instead of this..
            'If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1)) = 0 Then
            '   NR = 1
            'Else
            '   NR = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 2
            'End If

            Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Copy .Cells(NR, 1)

        End With
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.Delete
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        'Below is commented out to stop user being returned to Pivot
        ' Sheets(CS).Select
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the event triggers while the data is still being written to the sheet. You could retain the newly created sheet and delete the previous to avoid copying.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If CS = "" Then Exit Sub
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("DrillDown").Delete
        Sh.Name = "DrillDown" ' renamenew sheet
        On Error GoTo 0
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
   
End Sub
```